# How to get file information before saving it

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I have file contents which I am receiving from my form in string form (base64), and now before using `file_put_contents()` function to save the file, I wanna know the information related to it, like it's size and mimetypes and so on.
So the question is how to retrieve a file's information just by it's data(base 64 string)
For ex, let's say I have this string:-

```
Object {files: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAvwA…Fb+kScAm4BFwC6yGB/w9uNEwUj3EmdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==", text: "hi"}files: "data:image/png;base64,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…uBvGvg7j5HNenu62ICRmGCWAZNzFubhWWXH9Sn3gWiitDcZG8zE03aua3KvcWUbZj1ywD+vwBd1PSY0TCx2a2taKccFMC2qXdPuAyBFUAow0EXA1rT7YULABDEO4MOyCbCKSXOeiW8IcrVtgIzHjQtOyrCOYCHigYmpjfV1yJZLAs0mCjDHCGQ5aSMuWsPbyGto48RaoiaNfwtEMK7GvUezgs/xvgMkY7y1WaAhN+uJaKLE9SHzErnV78uUgH20p8862f8AMTQyLZKiMO+zUTlb1K61kA3nHvR56bpCC3/TDDvjsvkRD8ya+wic2wLTemrVpt6Jet9SSZqWVY2GGHghKVs8Z1OFjuOiJINbkzHI9i1z7w0auwpphw74m3TwUMpi8GMhpHbHRRgDDy9038B6lhygVdMNh7YVDsZZ1U78HS+yzXnLdHrkujedIFo3ZMkXAmCh/zHBjQs6tmCt1GLJR+LE0nbB6Es0Td3DbIcF/JOysXCRLLXc9fWMXdRLYDLtWcZZHvFu4V222acYSG4VSSx+XXrKaLEdQiYljv3SgHXORbNAWBf92mUd7H/OE33P2122HXVh3eM479MTCe+fnV/xvUlfM8MO5Ix3q9SgMA7w0xAzTcnBuzTvfjd1wA+GwTx/s7yyWMvqtEp6GZrem3Svrj2GlP0y10S7k3VBPIgD/nkG7RCuHWfVxsuNybpgAHT+CJiU+KJiImzDAy5pFJQeTOqW1oLvONdk8i2516qWYSAwJiQLzvC91BrFZ6cCNzSLX5sAMDyT3dKeMTL1fl5leoZ9FgafzqI7EFA0XVD7eD/Yr30Ct9J2W49DiVIzVOV41vNawA/gvIqGEoB+gvFSID1NLsyohj6FTKyHHYaVkg3uxtXPgFIqV5hfZxnqxgF+1E0Fc1L8Aj2V83jL6oB/Xmv5LI8xFTerdLZNHEGjUNtUoJPGR5PNHme9e/P8Tm9JwVzpgH8eQQ/tWoBrvPQMxMMnJqpZE0kXz4GXiptdYBIDaOj6vqgP4KXu2cCEh8lwFReoLmS/iDoo86EpU3TXNrWy2N0ip3mhlr1j47i+baKsWWviLOV7EqBYxPiy94ChokvQ1kX76e0p8YxRWVk1C7mNW1mGsaiLfkIdtOgCnLdZg/CeYC2bFNCOubALZQIyxrzFsY65Zhoon/R+WiWn/o6zT+elnVjA30VcB59l3DtCqkzdQDFPkDKVoi76jeOUMin1/HU1vuv12P6fsT474O+rE5ZZLyYSmxWHE0lfgBgvIq0ImAxKrGBN5IMXyyoyAGgAbPPwhJvc38tml/CQZGHdmU3HNgH/rO3tqVB0uVA0lSEmcQABLFoEIaWeFlqhSvjCQwD86Ecql0MCzBZEzopNWLWc8HY8QqGZ9XxNx+8yyhPgYT0qoXbSmFSPkWM8CoPW+1CEcG/OM1zbxr3f095PevHq3Hquy/NmkLGAfx5PAcfCtMBlGg7rXgRmpSlNv2zHHefBEoW9dLxiruJ4wVzFMVJ6fZflCpVcB/xdCn1odWHithMJJr95XXH1Z7TbSHcVmIt2Y0LAi28pOwA7TTiPQ+uPVW3PUKktnMTbpOIj4CeAnmQJXFR2IijJ3IeB9IFx6WPR3tKNXax1v8QzMwTAz/lqaJQSyLIJPxzzVoN0eas6NQy23XifSXWwsUv1rFOMUbHWfIBkvAttvAPzCARzgH3nMUdx53XMDfCa41nGxeHY3P40ftjMRfO0C9dybpjXU1AC+PHeTKLf1NMplz4XvQYFtJfSKqUc+qWeLQ/tR781NUI1uvGYwlRyOX7HKCAO+OcV8ipcj8XeTiQYEF1o/LQe4OWcR3PGizEt2wwpO4uegFehbxfRxll8y0W0Ydw95smiYzPQTFvEuJD2ldbNxryMy4CDd4sLSomV3sqJ/VaaUWPZgN/m2+7DkjrvOKWVs0TBpJdiiM8xrxxW6XqbxnhW1im8J8v05FGuWK/rSSjs3DAp8J7XkNbD96lvi3yb8TBp3wSm5J00J7fd9ItGq64Dd/HsTFLCxAbsq3kwURuZYq0at2Gnobs64G8j2FW9BiDfuiwxONpY/AkkmPqxDYWH1sxxVkzmk5/FOV7Vfli1ds9Da2nCN28iF47BtvxJu/jPoo7UF9Im7ZxWlose3yNYn7CY4z3F+wFFGAcBfwnQ5P2aWvdx3bIAv92YD89a4o3oqg+a1NNkZ1NSKn0OayLh/svinUPfEJzBar6IndTbPBneg3qyhWk0VtJ68GwNs7fMbB7nqq4s5JMCcGfdp+1aREViEVm/cK9l0Y0xl2L9sOPGUPQc8M8c6ZuwAF4qqwnCBQVttMQaxQwUsDw2CZSEUoB7jLNc4P6wrgBwlLRhE3bJoB9pmot1WsO5AHWd9QUTGNPMtVUoLOCfBcqm8U3bdpwF5NO8bQy6Ywq/0vs14e6zzmUAfvSljf8ZKti3ClGJ4jWUDB6l48XLrb4ELKecVuamXsFJUoD1GGC/7Xxbr9fuEmvrnJUzn+9VU3ryIgH/gEeSA/4Bd07vTYOWbTPrYJLAC4eFf1zgFsF+qRUO9Y/bKZg8ZLy8Q17ge++AFbgBFhHua9CkuTZzAPq7S0WOXqF5XKZcEEuoOi22MJ8pKlqyZi3INganBGjixm2s+xbQLmrfAUtnolVypuCWWGCW9dE2jfzpUjrVEh/Lb72JJEBgjjkXivSQA7DpBWM2Qb5f07IA2VgaekZLMAQ9Couw8A94ODngH3DnLKxpADRY5OscR/zPnVpvu02B3yywj4VuHMgH9QIArQ39Z2GC8BudJ4E2GUdgMbfxHVQkuxAvrdBtqTxsg81/XdIuPk9XFi7WN+19IO+0aVvbWPcXCfgx31hPX9ceoJL+bFMGYKN0V3NSsUoUyjZt8WtcAptBApir6kGvJXEUdo1hGvBp8mibw38zyNg8gwP+Tdahcz8Oc/nX05MRdDz++Pm3mJTSDKAGL/SQrQxzC2yTV0BKSal12aZvQ/8DIHeVU51eA1iESqw6k7qGSgzGdGkMCz1hs+g/JcOBlqxZGS+YlYOKeEkf2Bz2TWW0CEoPlH4u8JhjNrMBoC3fuGQMeRmXwGaRgF0zmgbVWoUBRqBJnuQmAfebRa5jnsMB/ybu3LkfDQDrwQfVsg+Q9fDDoxy+SfnxN0su57kFuAkqaMpf5wZFFpzS4gzgOk+mJabZmxVkO0vsBNxNdl7savdUS7eZZcmiosR7lwB+ymgWVWicjPoE/AD2zFxDF/6i09bNGhdd/85xP+947bpdXp9LYGgSwNxWmm643nYYFGmghDEBdTHxAVNTNplDhyabDtvjgL9DYW66qsZx9sfx8j0//qbr+vRATQE/AWedX0/ePSw4bYAeLTRd7PJIy3kTUDxtZ8gmvc97zwLv9KxAbqV9AFDNYOY2XrU+AD/6ms9Mzm1XtKgmcl9GWRv70WbML6PNfk+XwCpKwGb6GpfemOe6yjJUl1FTb+qSZOyAf0mCH/xtCfbJjwNAqXPtAEaQiWUeq+3gBbHmDSwFmxATLZoAnXVQZ3MENwX9qItjb979I9BOWpqb5KduIodJQ8Za92cBctJB8Lwl6SAhX1J/2gbddg340W62Cf3XJKvXZnnt2I9NxtpmeXZ/DpfAoiWAeRDzGOZAvHtMv4pP/N+HsYHGqHmSSCxITg74FyTolbqNBft1bZlZfLrMurJSwlmzxhIEAqTTPUqwik+cQxm6VAH2J4FyC/pLresAiQT7XQR3Wv7+LEqN7eouAD+DcGcFHLMcvRnM+DItw4TdobbtEO0K8HMjGs4diH9Y1/mCKWQxhmcpeW37za9zCbgElicBrGvATH0oEx0/lQP+jgW68tVZQMR0jHCDAcS5W3rlu7fxA9jNoaa5SktTpGFypHKAcUUlwn7CGlrfr6ELsI+H5+6TTfj7uK4LwF9iqce96h4I5pCG3Mb98ZmgIMwDrLsA/FZBQ3u7CHJuPGgHdgENKOhXn0MH1jneHJfAikqgBY3IAf+K9nVvzaa2OikXf2839ooHKQGmIrSu0fp3AM4m2VYwUQFwz1IgYBWFdbhJ3dOESECL+zbNj94F4C/JFMHNykCFITjkXggA9PYP7yqzB81Kl1syuPiMbXiuMBSsW1BuiUxZhrKp09lWwCrY5DG9rEvAJbAACbSkETngX0Df+C1cAi6BmgS4bTwAq1UgAIjAhWxhvZgqYwArq2Q0jQVYBOCHNZxBt3W6EbnwsOAzDS6z+OCzC3m1ecZ6UC760kHs+UNxXAwLPT7rGNvgE6JLwCXQXgItaUQO+NuL3K90CbgEVkUC1rrfZrfFNmC4Lptpuz2CtsNYhXF7A5C2Q0ux3Yyrq6D5ps8IpckqHbje/yZLAMoaFTfuUYJ+bBtk7bJ2CbgEXAINJOCAv4GwvKhLwCWwohKw27a34bk3BcPjxDQN8DNt6aSc7cyAxD0xoAA0CTou6bbSZ4QF38ZYgALUldJR0s5VLoOxV9+F2gH/Kveot90lsDIScMC/Ml3lDXUJuARaSwDUE1CF2tJNSsHwtAYyIL6epYdgHkBwUlAnzgMY9pkGd9Yzkr5DahSeo6v4itYdu4IXWnqPW/hXsAO9yS6B1ZSAA/7V7DdvtUvAJbBICcwCw6VtAVgGdYd/Njd/Fzz80naMKzftGeEhIX1nXXPqzyPb+rUW9K9A/u4uH93rcgm4BJYjAQf8y5G739Ul4BJYJQmQEtQmg419TtI56Gmgdb90X4I+ZUbAjzbCmwB6EahGBPqwRjt9p7seAOgH2G9DMeuuFV6TS8AlsCYScMC/Jh3tj+kScAnMIQFSgubdPIk52QGmAfQYqLts6z5EM2nPBXgloJA4fWeOAeSXugRcAi6B5UrAAf9y5e93dwm4BNZJAgD5TL1Ja/+8XoOu5Mc4ASglOBAUPARFpKvn83pcAi4Bl8AaS8AB/xp3vj+6S8AlsAQJ2BShdoOtJTTFb+kScAm4BFwC6yGB/w9uNEwUj3EmdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="text: "hi"__proto__: Object
```

54:783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$encoded_data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAvwA…Fb+kScAm4BFwC6yGB/w9uNEwUj3EmdQAAAABJRU ....';    
$size = strlen(base64_decode($encoded_data));
```

remember base64 encoding increases the original data in size by about 33%

Now we can write a function -

```
function getFileSize($base64string){
    $bytes = strlen(base64_decode($base64string));
    $roughsize = (((int)$bytes) / 1024.0)* 0.67;
    return round($roughsize,2);
}
```

this function will return filesize in Kb.

Now to know the Mime Type you can use [Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php)

```
$imgdata = base64_decode($encoded_data);
$f = finfo_open();
$mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $imgdata, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
```

Comment: Hey there, It's working like a charm, but I have one problem, I had to use substr($files, 22) to get rid of that data:... string, so is there any inbuilt way to tackle it, because obviously every file will be having different sets of data properties,

Comment: oh, and the reason behind sending the file as encoded base 64 is because I am using angular as my front end and there is just no built in way to attach a file to ng-model, and hence I am using this hack to get my way done.

Comment: use $data = explode(';',$obj->files); $encoded_data = $data[1];

Comment: That was really helpful, I spent the entire day, looking for the solution, trying million things but just not decoding data, I was using finfo but on the raw data. and stackoverflow again to the rescue. thanks.